# Twitter4J Login/Logout and session details

Tags: android, session, authentication, logout, twitter4j

I have a login button to login my twitter from twitter4J. once I get the authentication, I store the token and secret for the timeline updates to the twitter.

later on I want the user to log off and be able to login via another twitter account.

I am little bit confused how to invalidate the current authentication. and also I am unable to findout whether user is already logged in or not. the only way for me is by checking the token and secret variables. if they are not null, I assume that user is logged in.

during debug, if i restart my app, the authentication URL gives me error if a user had already been authenticated. right now I am restarting the emulator to wash off the user authentication

Answer (score 1):

According to me, everytime u login the website generates new access token and you cannot reuse that token, so I hope your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Please clear the cookie:

```
CookieSyncManager cookieSyncMngr = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(context);
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.removeAllCookie();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mTwitter.setOAuthAccessToken(null);
mTwitter.shutdown();
```

This will do, source
http://wenchaokong.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-twitter-integration-twitter4j.html